# How can I open hdf5 file from memory buffer using HDF5 C API

Tags: c, memory, libcurl, hdf5

I wrote a script for downloading a hdf5 file using libcurl, but I cannot find way to open it in c, I don't want to store it in disk and H5Fopen it. Is there a way to do the H5Fopen work on the downloaded memory buffer? Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called File Image and you need recent HDF5 to do that:

http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Advanced/FileImageOperations/HDF5FileImageOperations.pdf

Comment: Hi Anycom, I'm still confused on compiling that. Compilers told me that no symbol named H5LTopen_file_image. Is there any existing demos that can read memory hdf5 using file image?

Comment: I compile the source with `gcc  helloworld.c -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5`, it it right? and I've included hdf5.h and hdf5_hl.h in the source, but gcc still cannot link, responded with 'undefined reference to `H5LTopen_file_image', any suggestions? I used libhdf5_dev in debian.

Comment: It could be that the debian library is old.  try `nm libhdf5_hl.a | grep H5LTopen_file_image` to see if the symbol is present